# DAX - YoY Calculation don't work on higher Date level

Tags: powerbi, dax, ssas, cube

I'm trying to create a Year on Year and Month on Month Calculation using DAX for my Cube.
Here's my formula to get Last Month and Last Year:

```
Revenue_LM:= CALCULATE(SUM([CreditDebit]), DATEADD('DIM Calendar'[CalendarDate], -1, MONTH)) 
Revenue_LY:= CALCULATE(SUM([CreditDebit]), DATEADD('DIM Calendar'[CalendarDate], -1, YEAR))
```

It works well, if I break it down using the "Date" column in my calendar Table:

I only have data for start of month because that's when we do the billing.

[image]

Problem is when I do it at a year level, the Revenue_LY formula no longer work:

[image]

Same goes with Revenue_LM formula when I do it at a month level.
For LY, I've also tried using SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR but I had the same issue.

Is there anything I'm missing?

Thanks,
Kim

Comment: Does `'DIM Calendar'` have continuous dates or only 1st day of each month? (sorry to ask)

Comment: it has continuous dates

Comment: Is `Dim Calendar` marked as a Date table in your SSAS cube?

Comment: This actually fixed my issue! You can write this as an answer and I can accept it as a solution if you like. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure your `Dim Calendar` is marked as a Date table in your SSAS cube.